# Шаблонизатор html для метода .setHtml() pyqt

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Использую pyqt в своем приложении и столкнулся с вопросом хранения/генерирования html кода. На скриншоте снизу показано как я сейчас генерирую код, затем передаю это значение в метод .setHtml(), но хранить в таком виде мне бы не хотелось. Есть ли возможность подключить шаблонизатор по типу twig или аналога для управления, и не будет ли это сильно накладно по ресурсам? Может проще будет самому что-то подобное реализовать?

[image: Пример html кода в python]

Comment: Нашел интересное решение: http://alexmic.net/building-a-template-engine/
Попробую протестировать. Если есть более легкий вариант, то буду рад альтернативным предложениям.

Comment: Например есть `jinja2`

Comment: jinja2 не сильно тяжелый вариант? 
Внизу есть тесты, и цифры не внушают доверия https://github.com/alexmic/microtemplates/ (это код со статьи по ссылке сверху)

Comment: Мне jinja понравился (использовал в flask'е), а так, не было нужды искать аналоги и проводить исследования :) Посмотрел microtemplates и он кажется хорошим решением для простых шаблонов. Но вставлять, например, блоки `{% extends` microtemplates не сможет: https://github.com/pallets/jinja#nutshell

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, мне тоже jinja приятен, сам работал с фласком, но сейчас другой проект на qt, который мало имеет отношение к вебу, но требуется сделать простые вставки на html с передачей аргументов в шаблон. Вытащил код с microtemplates, он оказался достаточно легким. Пока перейду на него, но интересно посмотреть на то, как пишут другие разработчики в QT при работе с методом .setHtml(). Это будет полезным опытом. На гитхабе я нашел только то, что у меня на скрине - т.е. большая часть разработчиков не заморачивается, но это неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключил очень простой шаблонизатор. 
ссылка на статью http://alexmic.net/building-a-template-engine/
ссылка на гит https://github.com/alexmic/microtemplates/

В коде надо сделать небольшую правку.
1) Для питона 3.х нужно поправить эксепшены(нужно взять в скобки)
Находим в файле base.py:

```
except ValueError, IndexError:
```

и заменяем на:

```
except (ValueError, IndexError):
```

2) В шаблонизатор можно передавать переменные и словари. При попытке отправить dataclass поймал ошибку. 
Нужно в файле base.py найти строку:

```
context = context[tok]
```

и заменить на это:

```
if isinstance(context, dict):
    context = context[tok]
else:
    context = getattr(context, f'{tok}')
```

И еще исправить баг. Найти строку:

```
if_branch, else_branch = self.split_children()
```

заменить на:

```
self.if_branch, self.else_branch = self.split_children()
```

Подключил все это дело я таким способом:

```
context = {
    'out': outputs,
    'in_unspent': inputs,
}

input_html = util.read_html('input_list')
output_html = util.read_html('output_list')

render_html_in = util.minitemplates.Template(input_html).render(**context)
render_html_out = util.minitemplates.Template(output_html).render(**context)
```

Причем input и output являются списком объектов dataclass.

А вот так выглядит функция read_html:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..\\resource\\templates')


def read_html(engine, template_dir=TEMPLATE_DIR):
    html_file_path = os.path.join(template_dir, "%s.html" % engine)
    with open(html_file_path) as html_file:
        html = html_file.read()
    return html
```

Модуль очень простой и легкий. Для простых задач в методе .setHtml() вполне достаточно!

По производительности вот тесты:

```
microtemplates => run 10000 times, took 0.36 ms
django => run 10000 times, took 0.95 ms
django_default_loader => run 10000 times, took 1.16 ms
django_cached_loader => run 10000 times, took 0.46 ms
jinja2 => run 10000 times, took 5.64 ms
jinja2_env => run 10000 times, took 0.08 ms
```

***UPD:***

Дополнение - нашел баг в шаблонизаторе с выводом числа '0'.
Если попробовать вывести в цикле переменную с 0, то на его месте будет пустой стринг.

Фиксится просто. В **base.py** найти 128 строку:

```
 return '' if not child_html else str(child_html)
```

и заменить на это:

```
 return '' if not str(child_html) else str(child_html)
```